# SQL query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Can anyone please explain what this query is actually doing?

```
SELECT
    u.business_id,
    u.name,
    u.cusine,
    MAX(u.values1)
FROM 
    SOURCE_DATA u
UNPIVOT 
    (values1 FOR cusine IN (Sandwiches, Pizza, Bars, Food, Mexican, Thai, Indian)) u
WHERE 
    u.values1 = 1
GROUP BY 
    u.business_id, u.name, u.cusine
ORDER BY 
    u.name
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/) and [SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-reference) are different software packages produced by different companies. Even if both implement SQL, they extend it in different ways and sometimes use different syntax conventions that render the queries incompatible between them. Please use the correct tags.

Comment: I suspect the query is generating a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the query it looks like each of the fields, sandwiches, pizza etc contain either a 1 or 0.

Unpivot takes each of the fields listed and converts them into two fields, cuisine (a text field) and values1. Each of the original fields will become a row. Fields not listed will simply be copied down.

The group by is taking this and returning all combinations of business_id, name and cuisine from the original data where the field was marked with a 1.

Short version is that for each business_id and name it's getting a list of each cuisine marked with a 1 in its original field. Eg if pizza had a 1 it would return a row for pizza.